# one to one entity framework

Tags: .net, sql, winforms, entity-framework

Does any body know a good example of binding and inserting a one to one entity

I would like to bind and be able to make changes to both tables in a single winform using entity framework.

This customer form will have both data from Person entity and Customer entity
where person entity would have first and last name and customer entity would have joindate etc...

This is a one to one relationship.

Comment: Google: ef one to one relationship

Comment: i've google it and found nothing what i needed.

When i drag and drop from the datasource to the winforms the Customer object i also drag the Person object as details to the form, but nothing happens at runtime.

This is how i bind it on load event.
Me.CustomerBindingSource.DataSource = context.Customers.ToList

Answer (score 0):

Just use a `virtual Customer` property in `Person`.
No need to put a reference in `Customer`.

Please, find a complete project below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration;

namespace StackOverflow
{

    public class Context : DbContext
    {
        static Context()
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<Context>(null);
        }

        public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }
    }


    public class Person
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
    }

    public class Customer
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime JoinDate { get; set; }
        //[NotMapped]
        //public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
    }



    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var context = new Context();
            context.Database.Delete();
            context.Database.Create();

            var person = new Person { Name = "Mark", LastName = "Streisand" };
            person.Customer = new Customer { JoinDate = DateTime.Now };
            context.People.Add(person);
            context.SaveChanges();

            var p = context.People.Find(1);
            var joinDate = p.Customer.JoinDate;
        }
    }
}
```

PS. Actually, I believe that your scenario could be better designed with a `Customer` inherited by an abstract `Person` class. 
In this case, you would not need any reference to `Customer` in `Person`, since `Customer` itself would be an instance of `Person`. This would allow you to have several implementation of `Person`, all mapped to different tables.

Take a look to this snippet

```
    public abstract class Person
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        //public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
    }

    [Table("Customers")]
    public class Customer : Person
    {
        //public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime JoinDate { get; set; }

    }
```